# Consultar dados dinamicamente

Tags: php, jquery, html5

estou com uma duvida: eu tenho consulta no banco de dados feita em PHP que retorna números que são atualizados a cada requisição que faço ao acessar o navegador. Quando dou f5, os dados são atualizados e vejos eles na tela, até ai blz. Só que eu queria que esses dados fossem atualizados instantaneamente sem precisar ficar dando f5 no navegador e sem usar o request a cada tantos segundos. Queria fazer isso usando o Jquery por exemplo. Já fucei a net aqui e não encontro nada, só um monte de códigos que não entendo. rsrs

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: "sem usar o request a cada tantos segundos" <- essa é uma alternativa, a outra a é websocket. Se ninguem responder dou uma resposta mais logo sobre isso.

Comment: Server-Sent Events também é uma alternativa

Comment: Vou pesquisar sobre os dois e ver se consigo usar. Obrigado pelas resposta. Sérgio e HwapX.

Comment: Conseguiste resolver isto?

Answer (score 0):

Em jQuery seria mais ou menos isso:

```
        function refresh() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "url_da_pagina.php"
            }).done(function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
                //aqui vc trata os dados do resultado
            });
        }

        setInterval(function() { refresh(); }, 3000);
```

Comment: O autor da pergunta especificou que não queria uma solução que fizesse requisições a cada tantos segundos. Acredito que isso se estenda a requisições Ajax também.